# Json to mysql database conversion

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

i have a project in a class, to create a gallery with a database
the important part is the background itself

I downloaded a really cool gallery, but the images integration is with a json file.

```
[{
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/1.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/1.jpg",
    "description": "Zweifellos Mondbetont",
    "category": "photography"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/2.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/2.jpg",
    "description": "Mehmet Dere",
    "category": "drawing"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/3.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/3.jpg",
    "description": "Samantha Keely Smith",
    "category": "drawing"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/4.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/4.jpg",
    "description": "Kumi Yamashita. Created with thread and nails.",
    "category": "handmade"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/5.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/5.jpg",
    "description": "Alexander Semenov. Underwater macro photography.",
    "category": "photography"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/6.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/6.jpg",
    "description": "Borondo. Street Art.",
    "category": "street art"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/7.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/7.jpg",
    "description": "Anka Zhuravleva",
    "category": "photography"
}, {
    "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/8.jpg",
    "fullsrc": "full\/8.jpg",
    "description": "Guy Denning. Sketches.",
    "category": "drawing"
}]
```

it is possible to convert this to use a mysql database? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just convert JSON object to array and then walk trough in order to construct INSERT queries:

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lowsrc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullsrc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $json = '
        [{
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/1.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/1.jpg",
            "description": "Zweifellos Mondbetont",
            "category": "photography"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/2.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/2.jpg",
            "description": "Mehmet Dere",
            "category": "drawing"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/3.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/3.jpg",
            "description": "Samantha Keely Smith",
            "category": "drawing"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/4.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/4.jpg",
            "description": "Kumi Yamashita. Created with thread and nails.",
            "category": "handmade"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/5.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/5.jpg",
            "description": "Alexander Semenov. Underwater macro photography.",
            "category": "photography"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/6.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/6.jpg",
            "description": "Borondo. Street Art.",
            "category": "street art"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/7.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/7.jpg",
            "description": "Anka Zhuravleva",
            "category": "photography"
        }, {
            "lowsrc": "thumbnails\/8.jpg",
            "fullsrc": "full\/8.jpg",
            "description": "Guy Denning. Sketches.",
            "category": "drawing"
        }]';
    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    $link = mysqli_connect('dbhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname') or die(mysqli_error($link));
    foreach($data as $key=>$arr){
        $fields = array();
        $values = array();
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
            $fields[] = $k;
            $values[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $v);
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (".implode(', ',$fields).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",$values)."')";
        mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
?>
```

**SQL generated output:**

```
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/1.jpg', 'full/1.jpg', 'Zweifellos Mondbetont', 'photography');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/2.jpg', 'full/2.jpg', 'Mehmet Dere', 'drawing');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/3.jpg', 'full/3.jpg', 'Samantha Keely Smith', 'drawing');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/4.jpg', 'full/4.jpg', 'Kumi Yamashita. Created with thread and nails.', 'handmade');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/5.jpg', 'full/5.jpg', 'Alexander Semenov. Underwater macro photography.', 'photography');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/6.jpg', 'full/6.jpg', 'Borondo. Street Art.', 'street art');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/7.jpg', 'full/7.jpg', 'Anka Zhuravleva', 'photography');
INSERT INTO gallery (lowsrc, fullsrc, description, category) VALUES ('thumbnails/8.jpg', 'full/8.jpg', 'Guy Denning. Sketches.', 'drawing');
```

**Database content:**

```
mysql> select * from gallery;
+----+------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| id | lowsrc           | fullsrc    | description                                      | category    |
+----+------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | thumbnails/1.jpg | full/1.jpg | Zweifellos Mondbetont                            | photography |
|  2 | thumbnails/2.jpg | full/2.jpg | Mehmet Dere                                      | drawing     |
|  3 | thumbnails/3.jpg | full/3.jpg | Samantha Keely Smith                             | drawing     |
|  4 | thumbnails/4.jpg | full/4.jpg | Kumi Yamashita. Created with thread and nails.   | handmade    |
|  5 | thumbnails/5.jpg | full/5.jpg | Alexander Semenov. Underwater macro photography. | photography |
|  6 | thumbnails/6.jpg | full/6.jpg | Borondo. Street Art.                             | street art  |
|  7 | thumbnails/7.jpg | full/7.jpg | Anka Zhuravleva                                  | photography |
|  8 | thumbnails/8.jpg | full/8.jpg | Guy Denning. Sketches.                           | drawing     |
+----+------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
8 rows in set
```